# Blazor Server: Can't change ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server application with a set of custom environment variables, I am trying to set the environment into DevelopmentLocal on the web.config file, however It stays on the Development environment

This is the list of `appsettings.json`

[image: List of appsettings]

Program.cs

```cs
...
Console.WriteLine($"This application is running on the environment: {app.Environment.EnvironmentName}");
// Output: This application is running on the environment: Development
// Expected: This application is running on the environment: DevelopmentLocal
...
```

web.config

```xml
...
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="DevelopmentLocal"/>
      </environmentVariables>
...
```

Comment: What ```ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT``` you have set on your laptop? ```app.Environment.EnvironmentName``` reads from your local windows environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Check your launchSettings.json file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the launchsettings only works for VS, and in code level, you could add the variables in program.cs

**Add the variables in your program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

builder.Configuration
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
...
```

**Or you can set the env before running the project**

Set in cmd `setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "DevelopmentLocal"`

[image]

[image]